# What type of connector is on this small Li-ion pouch battery?

Tags: identification, connector, lithium-ion

I have some small Li-ion pouch batteries and I am having a hard time identifying the connector.  To me it does not seem to be of a standard "JST" variety but I am not an expert.  Has anyone seen such a connector used for a mass-produced Li-ion pouch battery?

I made some measurements with a caliper and made the figure below:

[image]

Comment: I removed your disclaimer because component identification questions are accepted/on-topic. Thank you for providing dimensions, but one critical one you omitted is the center-to-center distance between the pins (pitch).

Comment: QR code decodes to `XG2521265893`, same as the bottom line of text. That has not helped in finding any specifications for this battery/connector, however.

Comment: @JYelton that's not QR code ... it is DataMatrix code

Comment: @jsotola Ah, I didn't realize this obviously. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a [Hirose DF57H-2S-1.2C](https://www.hirose.com/product/download/?distributor=digikey&type=2d&lang=en&num=DF57H-2S-1.2C).  Some of the measurements are off but 2.6mm across the mating face matches.  I would double check the dimensions against the drawing.

Comment: For whatever is worth, I checked and I agree: Hirose DF 57.